# How can keep the 2 div in one line?

Tags: html, css

I have created a news banner and a button as two separate `<div>` elements, but I find them in 2 lines.

I want keep them in one line, how to do it?

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="newsbar">news bar</div>
            <div id="button"><span role="button"> <input type="button" value="submit"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/2/).

Comment: source at:   http://jsfiddle.net/sstong123/ZKKFU/1/

Comment: additional:how to set the news align center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#newsbar {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    text-align: center;
}
#button{
    float:left;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/10/)

Comment: how to set the news align center?

Comment: Yes Harim I have edited my answer. in `newsbar` class you need to add `text-align: center;` see here http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/22/

Comment: Yes,I see it,thanks Roopendra.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle. Add

```
float:left
```

to both the divs.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/5/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/4/

Set the two div's to have style of inline (or inline block as I have opted for in the example above.)

CSS rule below for inline block

```
#id { display:inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you research your subject?

```
 #newsbar
 {
     float:left; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a width for each  and then use for the first :

```
float:left;
```

and for the second div :

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKKFU/11/)

```
div
{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a width where there is space for 2 divs, than use

> Float: left;

this will put the divs next to each other,
ofcourse you could use any other direction of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/ZKKFU/15/

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="news-wrap">
        <div>
            <div id="newsbar"></div>
            <div id="button"><span role="button"> <input type="button" value="submit"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#news-wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#newsbar{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="200px" align="center">
<div id="outer">
<div id="newsbar"></div></td>
<td>
<div id="button"><span role="button"> <input type="button" value="submit"/></div></td>
</div>
</tr>
</table>
```

just make ur div's into a small table..

Answer (score 0):

```
    display:inline-block

#div1{float:left}

#div2{float:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css try adding

```
float: left;
```

*and*

```
display: inline-block;
```

That should fix it.